# Is the domain of $\dfrac{1-x}{1-y}$ a region?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The domain $D$ for which the equation $z=\dfrac{1-x}{1-y}$ defines a function is the entire plane with the exception of the line $y=1$. In my textbook, a region must satisfy the following two properties:

1. Each point of the set is the center of a circle whose entire interior consists of points of the set.
2. Every two points of the set can be joined by a curve which consists entirely of points of the set.

In the answers section of my textbook, I'm told that the entire plane excluding the line $y=1$ is a region. Although, I'm not sure how property 2 is satisfied. For example, the points $(1,0)$ and $(1,2)$ in the plane can't be joined by a curve without leaving the set.

Comment: Looks to me like an error in the answers. There’s a problem at the point $(1,1)$, but there’s no satisfactory way of making this a point of the domain of definition of your function.

Comment: Just for your information, the first property is known as being "open" and the second property is known as being "path connected."  And you're right -- $D$ isn't a "region" under that definition because it's not path connected.  (It's not even connected, which is weaker than being path connected.)